# How bugs should be reported in SCRUM board?

Tags: scrum

Our team has decided that All bugs related to specific story should be reported in the same story after reopening it as part of DOD. This also means that there would be no additional SPs for bugs.
Such bugs would be discussed as part of retrospective and why it was missed.

Is this a correct approach following SCRUM values? I disagree. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it not a direct software question. It should be asked on [programmers.se] instead, or [workplace.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to realise that story points measure the delivery of business value and are not about measuring effort. If work is done to fix bugs or on any task that does not deliver business value it is regarded as an overhead that reduces the teams velocity by reducing the number of story points that can be achieved.

The velocity of the team is not a measure of the performance of the team. It is a metric used to help with establishing the capacity of the team in future sprints.

Generally when bugs are raised on a story in the same sprint that the story is being developed then they are simply treated as part of the work required to complete the story.

If a bug is raised on a story that was thought to be done in a previous sprint then generally it would just be fixed in the current sprint. You would not typically re-open an old story just because a bug was reported against it.

Discussing why a bug was missed in the retrospective is a good idea. The longer it takes to find the bug the longer it usually takes to fix the bug, as developers are less familiar with the code that caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks Barnaby. i agree "You would not typically re-open an old story just because a bug was reported against it." Discussing  in retrospective why the bug raised is a good initiative though.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer bugs to be new backlog items so they can be prioritized.

I'll give you a scenario:

Lets say for a story you have acceptance criteria, and lets say your DOD includes meeting the acceptance criteria. This means that the story will not even be considered done until the acceptance criteria is met.

So any bugs identified after a story is done would really be stuff that have not been thought of in acceptance criteria. In this case the new bugs should be new backlog items and go through the prioritisation process and sprint planning.

however...

At the end of the day the scrum team must come into consensus as to what the best approach is in their particular case. In scrum we don't have a boss/hero/leader dictating the process. Such decisions are made by the whole team. So if you are not convinced your team needs to convince you. Or you need to convince your team.

Answer (score 0):

A bug is a lack of quality. In SCRUM it's the development team's responsibility to deliver a high quality product. If the product has bad quality, everybody will blame the developers. Therefore the team itself should take care how to handle bugs. Quality is not negotiable and this is why no one but the dev team should prioritize bugs.

We decided to handle a bugfix as the most important work item in a sprint. When ever a bug report comes in, we put a red card at the top of the WIP column and begin to work on it immediately. For us, this has lead to a very high quality product and high quality code and higher velocity.